# How does a HashMap determines the right Key without calling equals()

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

Here is an example of a `Person` class that I will use as a key.

It overrides `equals()` so that it always returns `false` and `hashCode()` that always returns `1`.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;


    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Equals is called");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("Hashcode is called");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now let's use it as a key and randomly fill the map.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var person1 = new Person("Mike", 21);
        var person2 = new Person("Alex", 32);
        var person3 = new Person("Andrew", 45);

        Map<Person, String> peopleMap = new HashMap<>();

        peopleMap.put(person3, "SomeValue3");
        peopleMap.put(person2, "SomeValue1");
        peopleMap.put(person1, "SomeValue2");

        System.out.println("Getting a person \n \n");
        System.out.println(peopleMap.get(person3));
    }
}
```

Here is what I see in a console:

```
Hashcode is called
Hashcode is called
Equals is called
Hashcode is called
Equals is called
Equals is called

Getting a person 

Hashcode is called
SomeValue3
```

Questions:

1. How could it determine the right key if the equals is always `false`?
2. How could it get the right key without even calling `equals()` for getting an object by the key?
3. If we move adding the person3 object down ( the one we are getting ) so it is in the middle  - `1` `equals()` will be called for the first object. If we move adding to the 3 position, like this:

   ```
    peopleMap.put(person2, "SomeValue1");
    peopleMap.put(person1, "SomeValue2");
    peopleMap.put(person3, "SomeValue3");
   ```

`2` times `equals()` will be called ( for `person2` and `person1` ) but none for the key we are getting.

Why is it so? I always thought that map can't store an order, but look like this.

Comment: "I always thought that map can't store an order" nope, the documentation says "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map" which only means "don't assume it will **or won't** be in any particular order".

Comment: Please look up what a hashtable is.

Comment: I ***really*** recommend using a debugger, this question can be self-answered after 2 minutes of using a debugger and seeing how `getNode` works internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `equals` implementation violates the contract of the method, specifically the first clause in the javadoc:

> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.

However the `HashMap` implementation assumes the condition holds and as an optimization will first check if the key object is the same by reference before using `equals`. You can see this when you look at the source code of `HashMap`.

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0f801fe6fd2fcc181121f9846f6869ca3a03e18a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L577-L579

```
    final Node<K,V> getNode(Object key) {
...
            if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
                ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return first;
...
```

You can also confirm this by stepping through the execution with a debugger.

Comment: As reference: `if (first.hash == hash && /* always check first node*/ ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))`. This is JDK 8

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0f801fe6fd2fcc181121f9846f6869ca3a03e18a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L577) for the latest source code

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` maintains an *array* of *buckets* under the hood. Each bucket corresponds to a range of hashes. Entries in the *buckets* are represented as *nodes* which form either a *Linked list* or *Red-black tree* (depending on the number of *nodes* in the *bucket*).

You've created a class with a broken `hashCode()` which instances always produce identical hashes and when you use them as keys they will end up in the ***same bucket***. So basically these objects would cause ***collisions*** in the `HashMap`.

After you've populated the `HashMap` using instances of `Person` as *keys* and invoking `get()` providing one of the *existing keys*, this method will internally invoke `getNode()`.

`getNode()` would find the corresponding *bucket* (based on the *hash* of the provided *key*), and if the contents of this bucket isn't `null` - i.e. the bucket contains either a *list* or a *tree*, it would traverse through the *list* (*tree*) checking each *node* and firstly before invoking `equals()` (*which is useless in this case*) it would use the identity comparison on *keys*.

```
(k = e.key) == key
```

And if the *keys* point to the same object, this comparison is fast and there's no need to resort to comparison using `equals()` (*which might be costful in case of the complex object graph*).

That's why even with broken `equals/hashCode` `HashMap` is able to identify the required entry, when you're giving exactly the same object as a *key*.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How could it determine the right key if the equals is always false?
> 2. How could it get the right key without even calling an equals for getting an object by the key?

you can refer `hashTable internal working` for detail information as it is difficult to explain it here. Have tried to explain in short.

- Every hash-based DataStructure internally follows `HashTable`.

```
    Map<Person, String> peopleMap = new HashMap<>();
```

- here `init_capacity=16` (HashMap) => 16 distinct *bucketId's* [0-15] , like an array of references, initially value= `null`.

*each slot of array is called as* **bin/bucket**

*Java HashTable internally use* **Singly Linear LinkedList**

- bucketId calculated internally like, `bucketId = @Overrided HashCode + some internal calculation`
- your Hashcode() returns everytime **1** implies `bucketId = 1 + (say)3 = 4 [everytime]`.

```
     peopleMap.put(person3, "SomeValue3");
```

1. invokes **Hashcode one time** => bucketId = 4 is empty initially **so JVM do NOT invokes** *equals()* & directly attach data **(node)**(in simple language).

```
     peopleMap.put(person2, "SomeValue1");
```

2. invokes **Hashcode one time** => bucketId = 4. Now **invokes equals 1 time** since to check if person2 value equal to previous added value ie. person3.

```
     peopleMap.put(person1, "SomeValue2");
```

3.invokes **Hashcode one time** => bucketId = 4. Now **invokes equals 2 times** to check duplicates . ie. 1time for person3, 2ndly for person2.

**hence output:**

> Hashcode is called
>
> Hashcode is called
>
> Equals is called
>
> Hashcode is called
>
> Equals is called
>
> Equals is called

[image: DIAGRAM:]

**HOPE THIS HELPS :)**